# batch file for making query to use with youtube-dl

Tags: batch-file, youtube-dl

I want to build a batch program to work with youtube-dl, and I want to ask some questions (choice command I think it should be) and depending on answers to build query which will be executed by main youtube-dl command.

Example:

```
echo Do you want to extract audio from this clip? (y/n)

echo Write subtitle file? (y/n)
```

And do this at the end:

```
youtube-dl -x --write-sub  some link
```

I hope I was clear, english is not my first language. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:Input
set opt1=
set opt2=
set /p opt1=Do you want to extract audio from this clip (y/n) 
if not defined opt1 goto :Invalid
if .%opt1% EQU . goto :Invalid
echo %opt1%|findstr /i /r /c:"y" /c:"n">nul||goto :Invalid
set /p opt2=Write subtitle file (y/n) 
if not defined opt2 goto :Invalid
if .%opt1% EQU . goto :Invalid
echo %opt2%|findstr /i /r /c:"y" /c:"n">nul||goto :Invalid
if /i %opt1% EQU Y set opts=-x
if /i %opt2% EQU Y set opts=%opts% --write-sub
echo youtube-dl %opts% some link
goto :eof

:Invalid
Echo You have entered an invalid option. Please enter only y or n
goto :Input
```

Comment: I removed echo from last line and now it works, thanks. What setlocal mean?I am new to all this...

Comment: How to prevent from not answering questions, empty string or something else besides y and n?